# я хочу залить свой ejs файл на сервер, НО что бы выводилась главная страничка нужно что бы файл был html

Tags: node.js, bootstrap, веб-сервер, хостинг

я сейчас работаю с nodejs, сss, html, bootstrap и с сервером, хостингом. Хостинг - sweb.ru, и на моих файлах html расширение ejs, хочу залить его на хостинг, но что бы открывалась главная страничка, нужно что бы было разрешение html, а у меня везде ejs, если я переименовываю файл в html, то весь сайт не будет работать. Нужна помощь и надеюсь понятно объяснил, код если нужен, то он вот:

```js
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs')
})

const PORT = 8080

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log(`http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```

```css
body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgb(48,4,51);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(318deg, rgba(48,4,51,1) 0%, rgba(43,21,64,1) 48%, rgba(29,29,110,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(318deg, rgba(48,4,51,1) 0%, rgba(43,21,64,1) 48%, rgba(29,29,110,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(318deg, rgba(48,4,51,1) 0%, rgba(43,21,64,1) 48%, rgba(29,29,110,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#300433",endColorstr="#1d1d6e",GradientType=1);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

:root{
    --color: rgba(42,9,45,1)
    --color_2: rgba(55,81,144,1)
}

header, cection{
    padding: 50px 0;
}

header{
    background: rgb(17,14,62);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(17,14,62,1) 0%, rgba(20,29,51,1) 100%);
}

.login{
    margin-top: -135px;
}

.singup{
    margin-top: -135px;
    margin-right: 60px;
}

.profil{
    left: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin-top: -99px;
    margin-left: 100%;
}

.btn-itd{
    display: block;
    margin-left: -35px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h2 class="text-center text-white" style="margin-right: 100%; margin-top: -20px">BlueCoc.online</h2>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-itd btn-lg text-uppercase text-white">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg text-uppercase text-white">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg text-uppercase text-white">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg text-uppercase text-white">Link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="text-end">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light me-2 login">Login</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light singup">Sign-up</button>
                    <a href="#" class="d-block link-body-emphasis text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle text-end profil" style=" margin-top: -99px;" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="mdo" width="42" height="42" class="rounded-circle">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="conteiner">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h4 class="text-start">12312</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Вам нужно посмотреть, поддерживает ли ваш хостинг nodeJS проекты.